# Function : bcmod is not available

Tags: php

I'm getting the following error while installing one of a joomla component.

Function : bcmod is not available. Please ask your hosts how you can enable this function in your PHP installation.

Comment: I would suggest asking your hosting company how you can enable that function in your PHP installation.

Comment: An emulation of the `bcmath` functions is available in *upgradephp*, using the commandline `dc` utility as fallback (= slow).

Answer (score 12):

you need your PHP to be compiled with bcmath support (--enable-bcmath configure option). If you're on shared hosting it is unlikely they will enable it for you. So you can try a solution from PHP manual from this page: http://ru.php.net/manual/en/function.bcmod.php I haven't tried it , but you can test it:

```
/** 
 * my_bcmod - get modulus (substitute for bcmod) 
 * string my_bcmod ( string left_operand, int modulus ) 
 * left_operand can be really big, but be carefull with modulus :( 
 * by Andrius Baranauskas and Laurynas Butkus :) Vilnius, Lithuania 
 **/ 
function my_bcmod( $x, $y ) 
{ 
    // how many numbers to take at once? carefull not to exceed (int) 
    $take = 5;     
    $mod = ''; 

    do 
    { 
        $a = (int)$mod.substr( $x, 0, $take ); 
        $x = substr( $x, $take ); 
        $mod = $a % $y;    
    } 
    while ( strlen($x) ); 

    return (int)$mod; 
} 

// example 
echo my_bcmod( "7044060001970316212900", 150 );
```

Comment: thanks alexey. i have a dedicated server and i have full control over it.  where to configure bcmod function.  do i need to specify in php.ini file?

Comment: you should recompile your php as stated here: http://ru.php.net/manual/en/bc.installation.php This is done by specifying --enable-bcmath to configure script. In order to not miss any other options you have in your current PHP binary, you can create a phpinfo(); page and copy configure string from there, add --enable-bcmath and recompile then

Comment: Since you mention you have a dedicated server, you may just be able to install php-bcmath (or something named similarly) with whatever package manager your distro offers. I ended up with the same error when attempting to use the neo4j-php-ogm package with Symfony. If you installed PHP via your package manager, search your default repos for the module before you go building PHP from source to enable bcmath.

Comment: I am using it to check the IBAN banking number.as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20983339/validate-iban-php. And it works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

You can install the bcmath package using installer.
I am using CentOS so my commands are relatively different. You can use according to your OS.

```
yum install php-bcmath
```

Once you install the package,

If you are using php-fpm then you need to restart php-fpm service using

```
systemctl restart php-fpm
```

You need to restart http server at last

```
systemctl restart nginx
```

Comment: It differs from on different php versions.
For ex. 
on php 8.1 it can be used:  apt-get install php8.1-bcmath
on php 5.6:  apt-get install php5.6-bcmath

Answer (score 1):

If you have a dedicated server, try the solution given here https://stackoverflow.com/a/25229386/8015825.

> Before recompiling, check the php.ini file and search for "bcmath".
>   You may find bcmath.scale=0. If so, change the 0 to a 2.

And then restart your http server

Answer (score 0):

Is needed install the library at Debian 10, also to do remove expired key of the repository before to install the bcmath

```
apt-key list 2>/dev/null | grep expired -B 1
apt-key del 95BD4743
apt-key list | grep expired
wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/deb.sury.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
apt-get update
apt install php7.2-bcmath
systemctl restart apache2
```