# Enable BCMath using php.ini?

Tags: php, bcmath

I need to enable BC Math, but I don't want to do it using --enable-bcmath, primarily because I don't understand that route.

Is there a way to do this using php.ini only?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge you must compile php with the --enable-bcmath option. Without it, the required code won't exist in the binary. Therefore, there is nothing that you can set in php.ini.

Comment: I can't accept your answer, as it's only a comment. If you want to put it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge you must compile php with the --enable-bcmath option. Without it, the required code won't exist in the binary. Therefore, there is nothing that you can set in php.ini

Comment: or `apt-get install php5-bcmath`

Comment: I'm getting `Unable to locate package php5-bcmath`. Does it have a different name now?

Comment: @nkamm In Ubuntu (and it's save to assume in Debian as well), `bcmath` is included as part of the `php5` source package and all `php5` binary packages in Ubuntu and Debian (since php 5.3.10 at least) have `bcmath` included by default, so you do not need to install any additional packages to get it.  [I can show evidence (for Ubuntu at least) that supports this statement.](http://askubuntu.com/a/416875/10616)

Comment: Just go for "php-bcmath", it'll install the most recent package (today it'd be php7-bcmath)

Comment: @manniL is right that `php-bcmath` installs latest - but be aware - you only want that if you also want to have latest php - if your project runs e.g. on php 5.4 , install php5 packages ;) Sidenote: on Ubuntu 18.04 I had to install this package manually (for php 7.2.1)

Comment: for me `sudo apt install php7.X-bcmath` resolved a problem

Answer (score 8):

Before recompiling, check the php.ini file and search for "bcmath".  You may find bcmath.scale=0.  If so, change the 0 to a 2.

Comment: "Number of decimal digits for all bcmath functions.", its not about enabling the extension

Comment: And restart your httpd server.