# Cross-countries bank accounts validation with PHP & Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, validation

Here is a "general" question which may be partially answered there and there...

I try to get information about how to validate bank-accounts information that are classed by countries.

Working on php / javascript (jquery), user should enter his bank account information. If user is from the EU, then it's somehow easy to check the bank details information validity with the IBAN &/ BIC information he enters.

Example and solution found here on stack :

[Validate IBAN PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20983339/validate-iban-php)

But, how to get this for other countries... I looked over google and stack and couldn't find any "global" information about how to validate "any" bank account on country.

So objective here is to build some kind of form where user can :

1. choose country (ANY, in europe or not...)
2. enter bank-account 'number' field
3. enter bank-account 'facultative info' field
4. check validity (only "chars/numbers" sequence validity of course)

If anyone has information about how to validate other bank details from other countries than europe please share :)

Thanks for reading/help

Comment: Here is a small/simplified template to explain what I try to achieve : http://jsfiddle.net/gstaskf1/

Answer (score 1):

I think a "general" check is not possible, because the forms of bank-account-numbers differs very much from country to country.

Well checking the international IBAN should be not to complicated and is International.

Here is an jQuery implementation:

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/kf332bhj/1/`
```

If you want a bank-account validation (without IBAN) or transform any bank-account in an IBAN then this page may will help you (german) 
https://www.iban.de/iban-berechnen.html

There its implemented but they also provide lots of information how its calculated.

Answer (score 0):

I needed the same thing for a project I was working on, and I turned my form into  a React component to make it easier for others to do the same (26 currencies supported, with validation).

You can try it out using `npm install bankdeets`, or have a look at the demo on http://bankdeets.co/