# How do Divide a H U G E Number in PhP

Tags: php, math, division, integer-division

I want to divide a huge Number by 97 in PHP.

My Number: 500105175408332501131480

In Java I used the Bigint Class but in PHP I cant.
Its also important that I am working on a Sandbox Machine, so I'm not able to use Composer etc. pp.

(Im working on https://platform.entwicklerheld.de)

Is there a possability to divite such huge Numbers without using an Lib like this https://github.com/pear/Math_BigInteger/blob/trunk/demo/benchmark.php?

Comment: Can you use one of the [two core extensions for math](https://stackoverflow.com/a/211548/231316)? Sample here: https://3v4l.org/PPP2d

Comment: Reference from geeksforgeeks https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/divide-large-number-represented-string/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Working with large numbers in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211345/working-with-large-numbers-in-php)

Comment: None of them worked, i cant use any Lib. It seems that the Sandbox im Coding in doesnt Support these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[BC Math](https://www.php.net/manual/de/ref.bc.php) can calculate with strings. I am guessing you want to have the remainer of the division only? Then [`bcmod`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.bcmod.php) would be your choice. Otherwise pick `bcdiv`.

Note: works only php 7.2+, before this functions cuts with int precision as well.

Comment: If I am guessing right and you want to validate IBANs have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20983339/validate-iban-php

Comment: I cant use bc functions, cause their not defined in my Sandbox... It sas Error: Call to undefined function bcmod()
I dont know why anybody would block that, but i cant use it. (i used it inside and outsite current namespace)

Comment: This one helped, since here u can find an alternative to the written functions in PHP: stackoverflow.com/questions/20983339/validate-iban-php
Thanks alot!

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it helped.