# Convert a String to an Integer with PHP

Tags: php, integer, overflow, substr, iban

How can i convert a String to an Integer without losing the zeros and preventing an overflow.

```
<?php
$iban = "DE85370100500123456403";

$d = 13;
$e = 14;
$pruefz = substr($iban, 2, 2);
$blz = substr($iban, 4, 8);
$kto = substr($iban, 12, 10);
$eine0 = 0;
$zweite0 = 0;
$zuBerZahl = ($blz . $kto . $d . $e. $eine0 . $zweite0);
$rest = bcmod($zuBerZahl, 97);
$pruefziffer = 98 - $rest;

echo "d =  $d  <br>";
echo "e =  $e  <br>";
echo "pruefz =  $pruefz  <br>";
echo "blz =  $blz  <br>";
echo "kto =  $kto  <br>";
echo "eine0 =  $eine0  <br>";
echo "zweite0 =  $zweite0  <br>";
echo "zuBerZahl =  $zuBerZahl  <br>";
echo "rest =  $rest  <br>";
echo "pruefziffer =  $pruefziffer  <br>";
```

This has solved my problem which I posted too before:

```
<?php
$iban = "DE85370100500123456503";

$d = 13;
$e = 14;
$pruefz = substr($iban, 2, 2);
$blz = substr($iban, 4, 8);
$kto = substr($iban, 12, 10);
$eine0 = 0;
$zweite0 = 0;
$zuBerZahl = $blz . $kto .  $d . $e . $eine0 . $zweite0;
$result = bcadd($zuBerZahl,'0', 0);
$rest = bcmod($result, 97);
$pruefziffer = 98 - $rest;


echo $pruefziffer;
```

With this PHP can now calculate with larger numbers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20983339/validate-iban-php ?

Comment: "Losing" what zeros? If you are talking about the _leading_ zeros in a value such as the `kto =  0123456403` your code outputs - you can't. _Real_ numbers never have leading zeros. Only when you _format_ such values for displaying them _as strings_, you can have such leading zeroes.

Comment: And such a bank account number like `kto =  0123456403` _is_ not a number to begin with. Same as telephone or house "numbers" aren't.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your answers and your kind disslikes.

This is how the code works now:

```
    <?php
$iban = "DE85370100500123456503";

$d = 13;
$e = 14;
$pruefz = substr($iban, 2, 2);
$blz = substr($iban, 4, 8);
$kto = substr($iban, 12, 10);
$eine0 = 0;
$zweite0 = 0;
$zuBerZahl = $blz . $kto .  $d . $e . $eine0 . $zweite0;
$result = bcadd($zuBerZahl,'0', 0);
$rest = bcmod($result, 97);
$pruefziffer = 98 - $rest;


echo $pruefziffer;
```

Comment: unless this is the solution to your own question, you should add it as an update to your previous question.

Comment: @mw509 I don't know how it's work... This website is overloaded for me

Comment: I understand. It can be overwhelming for a first encounter. You can use the edit link/button at the bottom of your first post.

Comment: @mw509 sorry... I tried but I can't get it to work... don't find the website user friendly.

I press on the code icon to be able to add codes and when I paste them into the field it is not recognized as a code....

Comment: paste first, highlight the code and click the code icon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sprintf()` function`

```
sprintf('%08d', 1234);
Output: 01234
```

in this example. The `%08d` format string specifies that the value to be formatted is an integer `%d` and that it should be padded with leading zeros to a total width of 8 characters `%08`.

You can change the `08` to about any reasonable number.

Am not sure why you want this but ideally, integers will not have leading 0s. supposing you want to do some math, you can do it with the real integers and after that add back the 0's but to actually have it in an equation does not make sense(from my point of view). unless it was a floating number that comes after the decimal point.

Ideally you can write a helper function or something that just prepends the 0s for you based on the logic of how the 0s appear