# Why I am getting output 0 while trying to convert a huge integer to hex in php?

Tags: php, hex, biginteger

I'm trying to convert `big int` to `hex` in `php`

I have tried this `function` from [How to convert a huge integer to hex in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539727/how-to-convert-a-huge-integer-to-hex-in-php)

```
<?php

function bcdechex($dec) {
    $hex = '';
    do {    
        $last = bcmod($dec, 16);
        $hex = dechex($last).$hex;
        $dec = bcdiv(bcsub($dec, $last), 16);
    } while($dec>0);
    return $hex;
}

$int = 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494336 ;

$int_to_hex = strtoupper( bcdechex ( $int )) ;
echo $int_to_hex ;
```

It gives output as `0`

I've tried above code in `WAMP` and `LAMP`
I've latest `php`, `bcmath`, `gmp` installed.

What am I doing wrong ?

I'm trying to generate hex to use creating `bitcoin address`

usually int

`115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494336`

gives HEX

```
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEBAAEDCE6AF48A03BBFD25E8CD0364140
```

---

**update 1 :**

i have verified that bcmath is installed and loaded.

```
php -m | grep bcmath
bcmath
```

---

**update 2:**

i tried

```
$int = 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494336 ;
echo dechex($int);
```

gives

```
0
```

i tried smaller int

```
$int = 556 ;
echo dechex($int);
```

gives

```
22c
```

---

**update 3 :**
as suggested by Mikethetechy

```
$int = 123456789 ;
echo dechex($int);
```

75bcd15

```
$int = "123456789" ;
echo dechex($int);
```

75bcd15

---

**update 4 :**

Issue solved by putting `big int` in `quotes`

i.e. using

```
$int = '115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494336';
```

instead of

```
$int = 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494336;
```

Comment: [you need your PHP to be compiled with bcmath support (--enable-bcmath configure option)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10626609/4248328)

Comment: what does it give before converting to upper? did you try $int_to_hex =  bcdechex ( $int ); first?

Comment: @Mikethetechy it gives 0, even before strtoupper.

Comment: @AlivetoDie my phpinfo shows BCMath support- enabled, bcmath.scale local value 0, mastervalue 0

Comment: try this dechex($int);

Comment: @Mikethetechy it gives 0.

Comment: set your int as string $int = "123456789";

Comment: @Mikethetechy then wont it be treated as string ? and will give different output ?

Comment: maybe this would help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539727/how-to-convert-a-huge-integer-to-hex-in-php

Comment: @BarclickFloresVelasquez seriously ?

Comment: See `PHP_INT_MAX` at http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a huge integer to hex in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539727/how-to-convert-a-huge-integer-to-hex-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works.

```
<?php

function bcdechex($dec) {
    $hex = '';
    do {    
        $last = bcmod($dec, 16);
        $hex = dechex($last).$hex;
        $dec = bcdiv(bcsub($dec, $last), 16);
    } while($dec>0);
    return $hex;
}

$int = '115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494336';

$int_to_hex = strtoupper( bcdechex ( $int )) ;
echo $int_to_hex ;
```

Can google up on *arbitrary precision*. Your system will have limitations on floats and integer values based on hardware and environment settings. I've used gmp for things like this - ideas is you use a resource, string whatever and represent it that way to work with it. The bc functions also expect strings! That function divides up the string, you manipulate it, and then you concatenate your results to form the output.

Good thing to look at might be: https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/master/phpseclib/Math/BigInteger.php

Comment: i am not pro, to understand, why this works , but this indeed works.

Comment: @AMB i think it is because of this line: $int = '115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494336'; . you had a space at last. not sure ...but may be because of that

Comment: @Mikethetechy No the problem here is that the number simply doesn't fit into an integer: 64 bits can only store 2^64 = 18446744073709551616 different values we use half of them for negative values and the rest for positiv numbers and zero. So we use them for the integers from -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807. The given number is still so big that we can't save it exactly so we store it as a float which saves something like 1,0 * 2^256. We can't transform that to hex anymore because it lags the digits. They aren't saved at all. If we use a string we can save all digits.

Comment: @Christoph thanks a lot for the explanation! i was pretty curious as in why this wouldn't work! so string did the trick here in this case.

Comment: @Mikethetechy It's a very interesting subject. Things like precision, floating points, endianess. Good things in our field to have some grasp of. I could honestly use a refresher.

Comment: @ficuscr yes u r right...i started looking into it haha. good that i tried to solve this question..and now I can learn smthng from generous ppl like you :D thxx mate